# Is it possible to list all my posts in a given chatroom?

Tags: support, chat

I am aware that if I click on [recent tab](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/11287/martin-sleziak?tab=recent) in my chat profile I can see the most recent messages in the rooms where I have posted something lately. (And I can view the same information in profiles of other users.)

Is there any place where I could see all my chat messages or, even better, all my messages in a given chat room?

Comment: Undocumented, but possible. See linked dupe.